How do I wire the switch for my ceiling fan with remote from 2 switches down to one?
I have a ceiling fan currently connected to 2 switches.I would like to take it down to One switch, but I have no black wire in the ceiling And the red wire Does not appear to be hot.

To be clear, are you asking how to wire the fan to be used with a remote, or how to rewire a 3way switch to be used as a single pole to activate the fan?

The red wire should only be hot with one of the switches on.  With two switches you should have two switch hots.  Pictures of the switch wires and the ceiling wires will help.

Is this a fan which has (or used to have) a light kit on it so that one switch controls only the light and one switch controls only the fan? Or do you have a fan which is controlled by two 3-way switches that allows the fan to be switched from two different locations? In the former case the two switches are usually located side-by-side in a 2-gang box, and in the latter the two switches are usually on different walls.
